# depth map of specific object

Tags: object-detection, depth, color-depth

everyone!
i am trying to find distance of an object(apple for example) from my camera(using a single camera) by using depth map created by neural network(like [pydnet](https://github.com/mattpoggi/pydnet) or [MiDaS](https://github.com/isl-org/MiDaS))
[image: this is what i mean by depth map(they are created with MiDaS)]
I have two problems:

1. I need a really good fps
2. I want to run the code in Embedded(like Jetson Nano) so I don't have a strong computer to calculate fast.

now I am detecting the object(say apple) with Yolo and drawing a rectangle around it.
I wanted to know can I have a depth map of the rectangle? I mean instead of calculating depth map of the whole picture just calculate depth map of the rectangle.
no matter what neural network is in use, i just want a fast one with a good performance
thank you :)

---

also, it will be helpful if you know any other way to get distance of the object from my camera, just notice that my robot is moving fast and I need a good performance and the rectangle transformation did not work well for me

Answer (score 0):

i have found the answer myself!
just crop the object and send it to the model. its not as accurate as whole picture but its looking good.